# Setting custom "root" folder to include/require php files within deeper levels easier

Tags: php, include, directory, include-path, php-include

I was trying to come up with a solution to a problem that I encountered while programming in PHP. I am trying to set a custom "root" folder. I am using MAMP in my computer, so I would like to set as my "root" folder something like this:

```
$root = "localhost:1234/project/";
```

I am trying to do this so I can use this in a file, such as file.php that for example is in a deeper lever like

```
localhost:1234/project/folder1/folder2/file.php
```

and then inside the file I can maybe require/include another file from the "root" file, such as:

```
include $root . "/functions.php";
```

or deeper within a level

```
include $root . "/folderx/another.php";
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

I tried `dirname(__FILE__);` but it doesnt really work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just remove the slash from your root link
`$root = "localhost:1234/project/";`

to `$root = "localhost:1234/project";`
and include your file like this
`include $root . "/functions.php";`

or
keep your root and require the files without slash